# SQL Server : conditional (IF-ELSE) on Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a scenario where I want to put a condition on a join, i.e if A = B then join on 1 set else join on another. Tables in both scenario are same only the conditions are different. I have tried using case but I get syntax error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table1] CUP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 CP ON CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode 
                          AND (CUP.ClientId = CP.ClientId OR CP.ClientId = 0)
```

What I have tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table1] CUP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 CP
          ON CASE
                WHEN CUP.ClientId =  CP.ClientId 
                   THEN CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND CUP.ClientId =  CP.ClientId
                   ELSE CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND (CUP.ClientId <>  CP.ClientId or CP.ClientId = 0)
```

@juan

```
 ON 
   CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND ((CUP.ClientId =  CP.ClientId or CP.ClientId <> 0) OR (CUP.ClientId <> CP.ClientId or CP.ClientId = 0))
```

Comment: Actually in Part 1 of my code data for both matching clientids and 0 are coming. I Want from only one of them

Comment: ... ON (A=B AND 1) OR (A <> B AND another) ... based on your ambiguous description. That should work

Comment: Case is an expression which is used to determine the result of a single column, it can't be used like this to control multiple join predicates.

Comment: It's generally much better to do AND/OR instead of case in ON and WHERE clauses.

Comment: What is wrong with the first query you posted? That is how this should be written and is syntactically correct even though you stated you get a syntax error.

Comment: I have updated the Question. I get syntax error when i try the case part.

Comment: That is because your case expressxion is invalid. As I said previously it cannot be used for multiple predicates like that.

Comment: @Juan I tried your approach, I get data for both conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll have to use `coalesce` for the `SELECT` clause
- Note the `CP1.ClientId is null` which removes Gordon solution's limitation regarding NULLS

---

```
select  ...

from                    table1  CUP

        left outer join Table2  CP1

        on              CP1.StateCode = CUP.StateCode  
                    and CP1.ClientId  = CUP.ClientId 

        left outer join Table2  CP2

        on              CP1.ClientId is null

                    and CP2.StateCode = CUP.StateCode 
                    and CP2.ClientId  = 0
```

Comment: Its a either or condition, I want data only from one join second join should return null...  Currently I am getting 20 rows, 10 rows from each table. The second table Contains matching as well as 0. IF matching found ignore zero

Comment: I don't get your explanation. If the 1st JOIN finds a match the 2nd JOIN, can't find a match by definition. P.s. IT would  be much easier for everybody if you just post a data sample + required results.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM   TABLE1 CUP
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 CP ON CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode 
   AND CUP.ClientId =  CP.ClientId   
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.CLIENTID = TABLE1.CLIENTID) ) CUP 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 CP  ON    CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND CP.CLIENTID=0
```

I tried it with this data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1  (STATECODE INT, CLIENTID INT);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2  (STATECODE INT, CLIENTID INT);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1,100);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1,200);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (4,300);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (5,400);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (4,500);

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (1,100);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (1,200);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (4,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (5,0);
```

Output:

```
STATECODE   CLIENTID    STATECODE   CLIENTID
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           100         1           100
1           200         1           200
4           300         4           0
5           400         5           0
4           500         4           0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two `left join`, one for the first value the second for the default:

```
SELECT CUP.*, COALESCE(CP.col1, CPdef.col1) as col1, . . .
FROM [Table1] CUP LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 CP
     ON CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND CUP.ClientId = CP.ClientId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 CdPef
     ON CUP.StateCode = CPdef .StateCodeCP AND CPdef.ClientId = 0;
```

Note that the `COALESCE()` assumes that the columns you care about are not naturally `NULL`.

An alternative method if you want exactly one match is `outer apply`:

```
SELECT CUP.*, cp.*
FROM [Table1] CUP OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT top 1 cp.*
      FROM Table2 Cp
      WHERE CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode AND
            (CUP.ClientId = CP.ClientId OR CP.ClientId = 0)
      ORDER BY CP.ClientId DESC  -- assumes `CP.ClientId` is not null
     ) cp;
```

Actually, you could use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` to get multiple matches.  So this is not limited to a single matching row.

Answer (score 0):

When a case is all said and done, it ends with a value.

```
case when SomeColumn = 4 then 1 end
```

As you can see, the return is a VALUE

you can use it to return a column in a join, but really you are returning the value in the column

```
select aa.a
from aa
inner join bb
on aa.a = case when bb.a is null then 4 else bb.a end
```

You cannot use a case to return an expression

```
case when aa.a = 4 then (aa.a = bb.a) end -- this is gonna fail
```

Use OR on these scenarios:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table1] CUP
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 CP
  ON (CUP.ClientId =  CP.ClientId 
      and CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode )
  or (CUP.StateCode = CP.StateCode 
      AND (CUP.ClientId <>  CP.ClientId 
      or CP.ClientId = 0))
```